# unreduced suspension

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is the definition $SX=\frac{(X\times [a,b])}{(X\times\{a\}\cup X\times \{b\})}$  of the unreduced suspension the standard defininition? If I consider $X=$ point, the suspension of $X$ is a circle. But I saw an other definition of the unreduced suspension such that the suspension of a point should be an interval. Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I would have said that the suspension was $X \times [-1, 1]$ modulo the relation that 
$$
(x, a) \sim (x', a') 
$$
if and only iff

1. $a = a' = 1$ or
2. $a = a' = -1$, or
3. $a = a'$ and $x = x'$.

Wikipedia seems to agree with me. It looks as if your author was a little glib, and failed to mention that the "bottom" and "top" sets of equivalent points were not supposed to be made equivalent to each other.

Answer (score 1):

One should have a picture and here is one, taken from the e-version of [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html) showing the suspension $SX$ as a union of two cones:

[image: suspension]

Note the special case when $X$ is a circle $S^1$ when this gives the $2$-sphere $S^2$ as the union of two hemispheres.

Answer (score 0):

In fact in my experience the unreduced suspension is commonly written in the way you did it, although it is wrong. What it means is: collapse one side to a point and also the other side. But NOT both to the same point. So this would be only right when quotiening is associative, i.e.
$$
SX = (X \times I/ X\times \{0\} )/ (X \times \{1\}) "=" X \times I / X\times 0 \cup X\times 1
$$

To answer your question clearly: no this definition is wrong (or at least not standard)!

Comment: thank you. Ok, you mean "=" is not true in general and the definition on the left site of the "equality" ("=" ) is the standarddefinition?

Comment: Yes precisely! The LHS is equivalent to the standard definition (with $X\times 1$ I mean the image of this subset in the quotient) and explains why many people abuse the notation.

Comment: ok, thank you, I understand.